# R: spacio temporal regression for simple data lon, lat, year, town, data1, data2

Tags: r, spatial, ggmap, r-sp, temporal

I am looking for a simple, general purpose regression library and use the example data for modelling, taking account for space and time. I am stat beginner. I have some simple data that have both spatial and temporal component. It is a standard data.frame with columns:

- name
- lon (longitude)
- lat (latitude) coordinates mostly of capitals of counties, major towns
- year (month can be also considered)
- value1
- value2

The locations do not move, the time component is year (can be month, I understand that then seasonality will be involved).

e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble::tribble(
         ~Town,     ~lon,     ~lat, ~year, ~value1, ~value2,
      "Gdańsk", 18.62723, 54.36528, 2013L,    200, 220000,
    "Warszawa", 21.10167, 52.24707, 2013L,    100, 130000,
   "Białystok", 23.17073, 53.11619, 2014L,    100, 230000,
     "Olsztyn", 20.48121, 53.77034, 2013L,    350, 150000,
     "Kłębowo", 18.10021, 54.59029, 2014L,    200, 200000
  )
```

Can you direct me the simplest to use spatio-temporal library and directions how to account for the location and time in some simple regression, eg, predicting value 1 and value2 columns for new data.

Out of curiosity, what steps are needed if location moves and time component is in days?

Comment: CRAN taskview spatial: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html

Comment: Thanks, so far after studying taskview and browsing various tutorials I am attracted (for the ease of use) to spTimer http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sks/research/papers/spTimeRpaper.pdf pp 20. example with NYdata.